# Getting values from multiple HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of dates for events that customers can book via a form. At the moment, I have some cumbersome `onclick` script attached to `<a>` tags:

```
<h4>New York</h4>
<a onclick="$('#buy-form').animatescroll({scrollSpeed:700,easing:'easeInOutSine'}); document.getElementById('date').value='20-24 January'; document.getElementById('venue').value='New York'; $('#resicheck').attr('disabled', true);">20-24 January</a>
```

This scrolls the page using the `animatescroll` jquery plugin, sets the date input on the form, sets the venue input on the form, and disables a checkbox. There are multiple dates for each venue so it adds a lot of code and is generally nasty.

I'd lack to package all this into a neat function, but how can I get the relevant venue and date text to use, bearing in mind the dates vary and there are multiple venues?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('a').on('click', function (e) {
    $('#buy-form').animatescroll({scrollSpeed:700,easing:'easeInOutSine'});
    $('#date').val('20-24 January');
    $('#venue').val('New York');
    $('#resicheck').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

This is the case for one link. For multiple links you can attach a data element on every distinct element, for example:

```
<a href="#" data-date="20-24 January" data-venue="New York">20-24 January</a>
<a href="#" data-date="22-25 January" data-venue="LA">22-25 January</a>
```

And then use the following javascript

```js
$('a').on('click', function (e) {
    $('#buy-form').animatescroll({scrollSpeed:700,easing:'easeInOutSine'});
    $('#date').val($(this).data('date'));
    $('#venue').val($(this).data('venue'));
    $('#resicheck').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

You can use jQuery (and javascript) to attach events and take out the code in html. Accessing an ID in jQuery is with `#[id]` and more information is on the [jQuery site](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: Am I correct in thinking this would activate on all `<a>` tags though?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the script:

```
function updateDetails(loc, date) {
   $('#buy-form').animatescroll({scrollSpeed:700,easing:'easeInOutSine'});    
   document.getElementById('date').value= date; 
   document.getElementById('venue').value= loc;   
   $('#resicheck').attr('disabled', true);
}
```

And, here's the mark-up:

```
<h4>New York</h4>
<a href="javascript:updateDetails('New York', '20-24 January');">20-24 January</a>
<a href="javascript:updateDetails('New York', '24-28 January');">24-28 January</a>
<h4>New Jersey</h4>
<a href="javascript:updateDetails('New Jersey', '10-14 January');">10-14 January</a>
```