# Getting .closest() div id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to implement the code given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20325788/1703330). I'd like to simplify it even further by using `closest()` to find the `id` of the nearest `div` and using that as the location, but it doesn't work - I just get 'undefined' in my text box.

Here's the script:

```
function updateDetails(date) {
    var loc = $(this).closest("div").attr("id");

    $('#buy-form').animatescroll({scrollSpeed:700,easing:'easeInOutSine'});    

    document.getElementById('date').value= date; 
    document.getElementById('venue').value= loc;   

    $('#resicheck').attr('disabled', true);
}
```

Here's the (simplified) markup:

```
<div id="Philadelphia">
    <a href="javascript:updateDetails('20-24 January');">20-24 January</a>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the href attribute? - It works, because it updates the date input.

Comment: Are you sure, that `$(this)` is, what you expect it to be?

Comment: @Syjin nope, how can I check? I've tried replacing `this` with `'a'`.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall you can check using your...console! `this` refers to window object as href doesn't create any function closure

Comment: @elendilthetall you can log it to the console with `console.log(this)`. I guess the answer of madskunk should work just fine for you...

Comment: @A.Wolff @syjin console.log(this) returns Window `{top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, external: Object, chrome: Object…` etc

Answer (score 0):

**in HTML**

you nedd to pass `this`

```
<div id="Philadelphia">
 <a href="javascript:updateDetails('20-24 January',this);">20-24 January</a>
</div>
```

**IN JS**

```
function updateDetails(date,this) {
               var loc = $(this).closest("div").attr("id");
               $('#buy-form').animatescroll({scrollSpeed:700,easing:'easeInOutSine'});    
               document.getElementById('date').value= date; 
               document.getElementById('venue').value= loc;   
               $('#resicheck').attr('disabled', true);
            }
```

**and by jquery you do like below very simple manner**

**Now in html**

```
<div id="Philadelphia">
    <a href="#">20-24 January</a>
</div>
```

**In JS**

```
$("#Philadelphia").on("click","a",function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
var date=$(this).text();
   var loc = $(this).closest("div").attr("id");
                   $('#buy-form').animatescroll({scrollSpeed:700,easing:'easeInOutSine'});    
                   $('#date').val(date); 
                   $("#venue").val(loc);   
                   $('#resicheck').attr('disabled', true);
});
```